# Failed to submit push notification to device token

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm, aws-pinpoint

I got the error

> Failed to submit push notification to

while I was trying to send push notification for Amazon Pinpoint using a device token. How can I configure gcm/fcm push correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the previous version. The newer version works fine. So, the issue doesn't hold any significance today.